# Read horizontal table into data frame in R

Tags: r, read.table

The `.txt` file is in the form:

```
high_quality 1.2 .9 .7 1.0 1.7 1.7 1.1 .9 1.7 1.9 1.3 2.1 1.6 1.8 1.4 1.3 1.9 1.6 .8 2.0 1.7 1.6 2.3 2.0

poor_quality 1.6 1.5 1.1 2.1 1.5 1.3 1.0 2.6
```

*high_quality line and poor_quality line have 1 blank line between them.*

I have tried:

`fabric_df = read.table(file="../data2/fabric.txt",sep = " ", header = TRUE)`

But got the error:

"Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, :
line 1 did not have 25 elements"

Does anybody know how to properly import this file into a data frame?

Comment: Difficult to answer without more understanding of how the data is formatted. Do we assume that there are 25 high quality observations, but only the first 8 have a corresponding low quality value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do `data.table::fread("file.txt", fill=TRUE)` which will give

```
    V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 V21 V22 V23 V24
1: 1.2 0.9 0.7 1.0 1.7 1.7 1.1 0.9 1.7 1.9 1.3 2.1 1.6 1.8 1.4 1.3 1.9 1.6 0.8   2 1.7 1.6 2.3   2
2: 1.6 1.5 1.1 2.1 1.5 1.3 1.0 2.6  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: Worth nothing that `read.table()` has a `fill=TRUE` option too, so there is not necessarily the need to jump to *data.table*

Comment: True! I never bother with `read.table` since it doesn't extend to large data sets well.

Comment: @algae your solution is totally workable but results in an in-between row of NA's

Comment: I ended up using `fabric_df = read.delim( file = "../data2/fabric.txt" , sep = " ", header = FALSE) fabric_df = t(fabric_df)
fabric_df = fabric_df[-1, ]` . Is this worth posting an answer?

Comment: If possible you should avoid blank lines in your data file, since they generally serve no purpose. (e.g. `sed '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' file.txt` is enough to remove them). Curiously, I included a blank line when testing this and I didn't find a row of NA's as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `fill = TRUE` with `read.table`. For reproducibility, I read in your data with `text` in `read.table`, but you can do the same with the `.txt` file.

```
df <- read.table(text = "high_quality 1.2 .9 .7 1.0 1.7 1.7 1.1 .9 1.7 1.9 1.3 2.1 1.6 1.8 1.4 1.3 1.9 1.6 .8 2.0 1.7 1.6 2.3 2.0

poor_quality 1.6 1.5 1.1 2.1 1.5 1.3 1.0 2.6", fill = TRUE)

# Or read in the .txt file
# df <- read.table("fabric.txt", fill = TRUE)
```

Then, once we read in the data, we can transform it with `tidyverse` (or in base R as shown below). First, I transpose the matrix, then I convert the first row to the column names using `row_to_names` from `janitor`. Then, I convert to dataframe and change the data type to numeric and reset the row names.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

df %>% 
  t() %>% 
  row_to_names(row_number = 1) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric)) %>% 
  `rownames<-`(., NULL)
```

Or in base R to get the same format:

```
df <- t(df)

# Make the first row the column names.
colnames(df) <- df[1,]
# Remove the first row with the names.
df <- df[-1,]
# Reset row names.
row.names(df) <- NULL
# Make the columns all numeric.
df1 <- as.data.frame(apply(df, 2, as.numeric))
```

**Output**

```
   high_quality poor_quality
1           1.2          1.6
2           0.9          1.5
3           0.7          1.1
4           1.0          2.1
5           1.7          1.5
6           1.7          1.3
7           1.1          1.0
8           0.9          2.6
9           1.7           NA
10          1.9           NA
11          1.3           NA
12          2.1           NA
13          1.6           NA
14          1.8           NA
15          1.4           NA
16          1.3           NA
17          1.9           NA
18          1.6           NA
19          0.8           NA
20          2.0           NA
21          1.7           NA
22          1.6           NA
23          2.3           NA
24          2.0           NA
```

Comment: Or just `transpose(read.table("file.txt", fill=TRUE))`...

Comment: @algae Still a few steps to get it into the right format though, but added a base R option.

Comment: @Andrew in this usage of apply should the second param in apply be a 1?

Comment: @ChrisKouts That would mostly depend on the format that you want it in. If you are wanting the data in a wide format, then I can take out a few steps here. If the param is `1`, then it will put the data back into 2 rows. Do you need the data just in 2 rows in columns or in long format like above? Happy to adjust!

Comment: @Andrew no problem, love the `df <- df[-1,]` . Didn't know you could negative index! It sent me through a rabbit hole, R is awesome.